# How to set paddings from left and right y-axis in a LineChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

How do I set padding from the left y-axis and right y-axis in line chart as shown in the picture? The data has a range from `1` to `n` points. The visible x-axis range is a maximum 5 points.

[image: a picture of a line chart where the first point is not flush with the y-axis and the last point is not flush with the right-hand edge of the chart]

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem? Please accept it if it was helpful

Comment: No it didn't, when I used it didn't work! But thanks for your answer. If you want I may upload my source code.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setSpaceMin(5f);
mChart.getAxis().setSpaceMax(5f);
```

Here's the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/) for those two methods:

> Sets extra spacing for `axisMinimum` to be added to automatically calculated `axisMinimum`

and:

> Sets extra spacing for `axisMaximum` to be added to automatically calculated `axisMaximum`

As you can see, they basically automatically add space/padding on the xAxis to the min and max, which is what we wanted.